# Angular @Output & EventEmitter not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass the value of `show` from my navbar component to my app root component which i am using to form the basic layout of the app. In the `navbar-component.ts` I have this:

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html'
})
export class NavbarComponent {

    public show = true;
    @Output() showEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    constructor() { }

    sendToggle() {
        if (this.show === true) {
            this.show = false;
        } else {
            this.show = true;
        }
        this.showEvent.emit(this.show);
    }

}
```

and then in the template I have this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-transparent ml-2 mr-auto"
    (click)="sendToggle()">
    <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>{{ show }}
</button>
```

I added `{{ show }}` just so that I can see the state of `show` change per the `sendToggle()` method.

Then I set up the `app-component.ts` like this to listen for the event:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {

    public show: boolean;

    getToggle($event) {
        this.show = $event;
    }

}
```

and then on the template I have this:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div id="wrapper">
    <nav (showEvent)="getToggle($event)" id="sidebar" [ngClass]="{show: show}">
        {{ show }}
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
        <app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

so when I click the button I can see the state of `show` change within the navbar component, however the app component does not seem to be getting the message. What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should put the `showEvent` on the actual component selector `app-navbar` that has the `@Output` decorator and not on the `nav` element:

```
<app-navbar (showEvent)="getToggle($event)"></app-navbar>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue and I'm putting it in the correct place unable to solve this

Answer (score 4):

You've got your handler on the wrong element (nav instead of app-navbar)

```
<app-navbar (showEvent)="getToggle($event)"></app-navbar>
```